# env: illegal option -- 0

Tags: shell, unix, environment-variables

I'm trying to use the command: `env -0` but it give me this output:

```
env: illegal option -- 0
usage: env [-iv] [-P utilpath] [-S string] [-u name]
  [name=value ...] [utility [argument ...]]
```

Bash version: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)

OS: macOS Big Sur 11.6.8

How can I make the `env` command understand the -0 flag?

Comment: macOS comes with the BSD version of `env`, which doesn't support `-0` like the GNU version does. (This hasn't nothing to do with `bash`, by the way.)

Comment: "How can I make the env command understand the -0 flag?" -- install [tag:homebrew] to get access to the GNU coreutils env.

Comment: @glennjackman I have installed already homebrew, and I also already have coreutils

Comment: Then you have 2 choices: 1) ensure the path to the GNU env is _earlier_ in your PATH, or 2) use the full path to GNU env

Comment: or use `genv`. All GNU tools are prefixed with `g` to avoid conflicts with BSD tools

Comment: Removed the bash tag, since `env` is not part of bash, and works the same way no matter which shell invokes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have options:

- `env | tr '\12' '\0'`

  Pass newline separated `env` output through `tr` to change newlines to \0.
- `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/coreutils/9.1/libexec/gnubin/env`
  Supply fill path to `env`.
- Modify your PATH/path variable in any of these `~/.zshrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.cshrc`, or `~/.login` to the directory of `genv`.
  If you are unsure of where genv is installed, do this `find /opt/homebrew /usr/local -name genv -print`.